# Как в отладчике Eclipse CDT посмотреть std::vector

Tags: c++, eclipse, отладка, cdt

Не знает ли кто способ просмотра в отладчике CDT stl-переменных, хотя бы `std::vector`.

Способ смотреть `_M_start` с помощью `Display As Array...` знаю, но он уже достал.

Может есть какой-то plugin?

Comment: Обычно это работает из коробки. Какой у вас тулчейн?

Comment: @user7860670, у меня два: cross gcc в ubuntu для raspberry pi и CCES от Analog Devices. Может в gdb чего то не хватает, если из коробки работает...

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо за хорошую мысль, в ubuntu для ubuntu и правда всё работает ...